# How can I switch out one UserControl for another during runtime within a Window in WPF?

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, window, viewmodel

I have a portion of a Window that should display one of several UserControls. Each UserControl presents the same data, only in a different format, arrangement, and style. The particular UserControl that will be presented in this section of the Window should be determined by a single setting that is stored in the ViewModel of the Window.

How can I make it so that the program end user can change the UserControl that is displayed in the Window at run-time?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your problem, but if I'm reading it correctly, just google one of the many tutorials on creating bindings in code rather than xaml.

Comment: I just changed the title of this question. Maybe this will help you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In my ViewModel, I have a `UserControl` property called `SelectedUC`, and another property, called `Style`, that is an `enum` type, which enumerates the different `UserControls` that I am using. In the `set` part of the `Style` property I have `OnPropertyChanged("SelectedUC");` The `get` part of the `SelectedUC` property has a switch-case statement that sets the field of the `SelectedUC` to a new instance of the corresponding type of `UserControl` and passes the ViewModel (`this`) as a parameter.

```
private MyStyleEnum _style = MyStyleEnum.OneStyle;
public MyStyleEnum Style
{
    get { return _style; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _style)
        {
            _style = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Style");
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedUC");
        }
    }
}

private UserControl _selectedUC;
public UserControl SelectedUC
{
    get
    {
        switch (Style)
        {
            case MyStyleEnum.OneStyle:
                _selectedUC = new ucOneControl(this);
                break;
            case MyStyleEnum.AnotherStyle:
                _selectedUC = new ucAnotherControl(this);
                break;
        }
        return _selectedUC;
    }
    set { _selectedUC = value; }
}
```

In my `MainView`'s xaml, I have a `ContentPresenter` with the `Content` property bound to the `SelectedUC` property in the ViewModel.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedUC}" />
```

In my `SettingsView`'s xaml, I have a group of `RadioButton`s that are all bound to the `Style` property and use a `Converter` and `ConverterParameter`.

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.View.SettingsView"
        xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModel">
<Window.Resources>
    <cv:EnumToBoolConverter x:Key="EBConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<RadioButton Content="One" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Style, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=EBConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static Member=vm:MyStyleEnum.SingleLine}}"/>                       
</Window>
```

EnumToBoolConverter.cs:

```
public class EnumToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter.Equals(value))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One (quick but not necessarily best) way is to add a ContentControl to your window

```
<ContentControl Name="cc" />
```

Then set the content of it however you like. Eg. set it in code-behind

```
cc.Content = new UserControl1();
```